# Delete Curve geometry based on edge Angle

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Can I delete parts of a curve based on black and white values .

I have a mesh that deforms
[image]

I have a curve attached to that mesh
[image]

I have created a edge selection using the edge angle node on the deformed mesh
[image]

I want to delete parts of the curve where the curve is next to the black. essentially transfering the colour information and converting it to a boolean so i get the curve geometry appearing only when it turns white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer to your title:

"Delete (Curve) geometry based on edge Angle"

you can just use a compare node and compare it with whatever angle you want and e.g. delete the edges like in this gif:

[image]

Yes, that's not the solution with "black and white values", but i have no idea how you created that curve and how you colored it. So if you could extend your question a bit so that it is clear how you created the curve it would be very helpful to be able to answer the question fully.